# Pausing/suspending entire Erlang program

Tags: erlang

Is there a simple way to suspend/pause an entire Erlang program without resorting to using OS commands (e.g. sysinternals pssuspend for Windows)?

Ideally I would like to resume the program on return from an external program.

Comment: I have two models; a control/communication network model in Erlang and an electricity network model in Matlab. I need to pause my Comms model whilst the electricity network model updates.

Comment: I assume you use Erlang as a bridge between your Matlab model and external world. Erlang program is a set of intercommunicating processes. So you can switch your communcation processes to 'pause' mode and don't process incomming messages. You can do it via custom process (erlang process) state. If you need to not lost incoming messages you can store it in any queue and process it after resume.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this approach. However I think there may be a significant delay if I have to send a pause/resume message to all processes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the short answer to my question is 'no'.

You can send a pause message to all processes. However it is difficult to know in what order processes will stop and there could be a relatively large time delay if a lot of processes are used. In the end I did use pssuspend to do this:

In Erlang:

```
runmyscript() ->
  receive
       updatemodel->
           os:cmd("start myscript.bat"),
...
end.
```

In myscript.bat

```
pssuspend werl.exe
mycommands
...
pssuspend -r werl.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

As W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv said you can "pause" process.

To perform that and not lose all the messages that were sent to your process while it was paused do selective receive. Assuming that your process is a gen_server it can look like this:

```
handle_info(pause, State) ->
    receive 
        unpause ->
            {noreply, State}
    end;
```

Note that all messages will be there, in receiving queue of your process. So if you are processing messages in a way dependant on system clock value, you need to move time sampling to sender process.